# How to struct-copy a field only known at runtime in Racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

In Racket, it's possible to make a copy of a struct with particular fields changed. The following:

```
(struct foo (a b c))
(define tst (foo 1 2 3))
(struct-copy foo tst [a 4])
```

Should produce `(foo 4 2 3)`.

I was wondering, what if the field I want to modify isn't known at compile time? Say for instance I want to write a function that can modify either a, b, or c depending on user input. If I have a function:

```
(define (update-foo somefoo param)
  (struct-copy foo somefoo [param 4]))
```

Then I receive the error `struct-copy: accessor name not associated with the given structure type`. Because it's treating 'param' as an accessor, rather than evaluating it and treating the symbol/string inside as an accessor.

So I was wondering, is it possible to use struct-copy where the intended field name is known only at runtime? And if not, is there a workaround of some sort, or should I just bite the bullet and change foo to a mutable struct (as `set-foo-a!` and the like exist at runtime)?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your question. FWIW, I upvoted it. Although (as I explained in a comment below) it seems like you actually will want to use a dictionary instead of a struct, I think your question is reasonable. In fact it's a good opportunity to understand the respective advantages of structs and dicts in Racket.

Comment: @GregHendershott thanks, could you submit that as an answer and I'll accept it. I didn't consider a dictionary as I wasn't planning on adding fields at runtime. Some other languages allow reflection on object fields without requiring the object be a dictionary, like JVM languages and Go, so I thought there might be a way to do it in Racket. As I implied, if I was trying to mutate the object rather than struct-copy it then I wouldn't have problems, as mutator functions exist at runtime.

Comment: I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This was originally a comment, but OP asked me to post it as an answer)*

If you want to have arbitrary runtime field names, then it sounds like you're duck-typing a dictionary not a struct... in which case you should use a dictionary.

One characteristic of a Racket `struct` is that referencing a field can be faster precisely because it's a static offset known at compile time. Another characteristic is that you can't add a field unknown at compile time, or, omit a field.

When those characteristics are advantages (i.e. when you don't want to add or omit fields accidentally), you should use a struct. Otherwise (i.e. when you do want to add or omit fields intentionally -- which sounds like your situation) you should probably instead use some sort of dictionary, e.g. a hash-table or association list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a syntactic extension:

```
(define-syntax-rule (update-foo somefoo param)
  (struct-copy foo somefoo [param 4]))
```

testing:

```
> tst
(foo 1 2 3)
> (update-foo tst b)
(foo 1 4 3)
```

The macro stepper in Racket shows the following transformation:

from

```
(module anonymous-module racket
  (#%module-begin
   (struct foo (a b c) #:transparent)
   (define tst (foo 1 2 3))
   (define-syntax-rule (update-foo somefoo param) (struct-copy foo somefoo [param 4]))
   (update-foo tst b)))
```

to

```
(module anonymous-module racket
  (#%module-begin
   (struct foo (a b c) #:transparent)
   (define tst (foo1 1 2 3))
   (define-syntax-rule (update-foo somefoo param) (struct-copy foo somefoo [param 4]))
   (struct-copy foo tst [b 4])))
```

Comment: Would that work with a dynamically generated parameter name? It seems to fail when I try something like: 

`(update-foo tst (string->symbol (read-line)))`

Comment: If you have arbitrary runtime field names, then it seems like maybe you're duck-typing a `dictionary` not a `struct`... and should use a `dictionary`. One characteristic of a `struct` is that referencing a field can be faster precisely because it's a static offset known at compile time. Another characteristic is you can't glom in some extra, unexpected field, or omit one. When those characteristics are advantages, you should use a struct. When they're not (sounds like your situation?) you should probably instead use some sort of dictionary, e.g. a hash-table or association list.